# Uses a javascript function into wp scheduled event

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a cron that is executed each second. This cron executes a function which calls a javascript .js file and it must show an alert on the page.

This is the main idea but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Here's my code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');

if ( !wp_next_scheduled('check_script') ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'second', 'check_script_hook' );
}

function checkScript()
{
    check();


}
add_action('check_script_hook', 'checkScript');

function check()
{
    echo("running");

    wp_enqueue_script('script', plugins_url('js/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),true,'1.2.1');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script');
```

PD: The wp cron works correctly. If I put a echo into the function that is executed each second it works.

Comment: the user has to request the page. by the time the cron is running, its outside the scope of a request.

Comment: But a request to where? To the page? Or to the admin page?
Thanks for your help!